# Как поправить историю коммитов

Tags: git

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, до коммита 6cd0ffe образовалось какая то петля, как ее убрать?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что нужно сделать. Петлей вы называете комиты 7c28c1a, 6512307? 6cd0ffe это комит, который возник в результате слияния ветки make в master. Какую историю комитов вы хотете получить в результате?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то вы опасаетесь, что в данном состоянии "что-то пошло не так", т.к. история не выглядит так, как выглядела до этого с другими ветками, правильно?

Comment: Верно, после коммита 7c28c1a возникает какой то пробел, это ошибка или нет?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Не стоит этого делать. Почитайте книжку ProGit, что ли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом фрагменте истории видно что до комита `785321e` разработка велась таким образом: каждый раз чтобы добавить новую функцию или исправить ошибку создавалась новая ветка. После окончания работы в ветке она сливалась в `master`.

Важный момент, что всегда в работе была только одна ветка (не считая `master`).

После `785321e` видно важное изменение, а именно: от этого комита породили две паралельных ветки - `make` и `modes`. Поэтому история разошлась. Работа велась параллельно в двух ветках.

Далее, ветка `make` была слита в `master`, а `modes` - еще нет (кроме того от нее породили  еще одну ветку - `menu`).

Именно так следует читать красную трехпутевую (если можна так выразиться) развилку и петлю после комита `785321e`.

В этом нет ничего страшного, это обычное дело, когда ведется параллельная работа.

Есть возможность удалить разветвление путем переноса базы веток `modes` и `menu` на комит `6cd0ffe`. Это можно сделать командой `git rebase`, но я бы не заморачивался.

Comment: `git rebase ...` ломает историю, а это у новичков часто чревато...